# asyncio.sleep is blocking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, sanic

I am running the below code. 3 requests for each (3 browser tabs that I am quickly refreshing).

The first `time.sleep` takes 60s for all requests to run as I am blocking.

The second `asyncio.sleep` runs all 3 requests instantly as I am not awaiting.

The third `await asyncio.sleep` is taking 20s for the first request, then another 10 for the second and then another 10 for the third. i.e. 40s total. I would expect that I could run a large amount of requests all in around 20s as I am not supposed to be blocking?

```py
import asyncio
import time
from datetime import datetime

from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json

app = Sanic()

@app.route("/")
async def test(request):
    # time.sleep(20)
    # asyncio.sleep(20)
    await asyncio.sleep(20)
    return json({"hello": datetime.now().isoformat()})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Comment: No, `asyncio.sleep` does not block and your code example works exactly as intended and you expect it to work — if multiple requests came around 00:00, they would finish around ~00:20. There may be a mistake in how you test. By chance, do you test with a browser?

Comment: yes i just used a browser

Comment: Browsers may limit parallel requests to the same URL. Try making each request unique by adding a unique parameter to a request like `localhost:8000/?id=1` and setting different id.

Comment: yes it is the browser, thanks!

Comment: @Fian Please consider writing up the comment as an answer, do that Lee can accept it, thus resolving the question.

Comment: Actually, there _is_ somewhere on the SO with quite the same question and answer (because I've gained knowledge about a such browser behavior here), but I was unable to find it to mark question as a duplicate.